# converting normal website in mobile

Tags: mobile-website

I am developping Mobile Application but i am not getting any idea on how a normal URL is converting in mobile like http://www.google.com it is a  normal url but it is openning in mobile like http://m.google.com like this  for that i have to do any thing or not i dont know please let me know the steps for that if any one knows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would check the [user agent string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) when a user makes a request to your site.  How you would do this is dependent on your server-side programming language/environment.  But when you check the string you would simply compare it to known "mobile browsers" and would forward the user to the other URL accordingly.

It's not really "changing the URL" to something other than a "normal URL" it's just checking a condition at the request time and forwarding the user to a different site if the condition is met.